# Is it possible to retrieve xml files of Profile from workbench

Tags: deployment, profile, xml, workbench

Can someone help us how can we retrieve all profiles using workbench?
Can you check what is wrong with our file?

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
    <members></members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <version>40.0</version>
</Package>`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed asterisk * symbol, that represents "all elements". Use the following content of the `package.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <version>40.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: hi @alexander. Thanks for the reply, is it possible to retrieve the list of profile in an xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you include objects, fields or components that a profile has access to, in a package.xml, you will not get those details.